# Python/Selenium, how to access html list without id, but has mutlitple list of same class on page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and was wondering how to correctly find items in the html list below.  The issue I am having is the html list does not have an 'id' directly, it is in a 'span' a couple of lines above.  The page has a few of these an they all have the same class "selectUL".  In this example case it is the "lang" list, but there is also region, timezone etc.

I am trying to write a function that takes a 'field'(lang region etc) and use that to find_element_by_xpath to parse it out and eventually report which one is selected (and or another function to set the selection)

So...  assuming browser is webdriver.Chrome() and I was able to log in etc.

```
field = "lang"
# obviously not working but hopefully concept makes sense
sysEntry = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='{}']//ul[contains(@class, 'selectUL')]".format(field))
```

Web Page snippit looks like:

```
<table class="info_table conf_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td class="head" colspan="2">Language / Country</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="sub_head">Language</td>
      <td class="content normal">
         <div class="selectbox selectmenu">
            <a class="selectbtn">
               <span id="lang" class="selecttext">None</span>
               <span class="select-arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="selectUL">
               <li id="langEN" class="sel"><a href="javascript:">English</a>
               </li>
               <li id="langFR"><a href="javascript:">French</a>
               </li>
               <li id="langGE"><a href="javascript:">German</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
```

How do I access these so that I can read from/write to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier way to do this is to look for `class="sel"` on the `LI`. That seems to indicate which option is selected. From there, you can grab the `A` inside and then the text inside the `A`. You can use a CSS Selector to find this element using "li.sel > a" then grab the text inside that element. Something like

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.sel > a").text
```

This should return "English" from your HTML sample above.

---

Let's go a slightly different but more specific route. We can use XPath to find the TD that contains "Language" and then down through the children from there to find the `LI` with class `sel` and then get the `A` that contains the text you want.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='sub_head'][text()='Language']/following-sibling::td//li[@class='sel']/a").text
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and only get u'' for response, so something is not quite right.  This could be because there are multiple lists like this on the config page (one for language, another for region, timezone etc) so it could be getting the wrong actual list?    How do you set this to look at another list (starting with a span id of "region" etc) and or how to use it to set langGE above .

Comment: Interesting... you are probably right. There are probably other selections on the page that match the CSS Selector I'm using. I updated my answer to use XPath and hopefully be specific enough to find what you are looking for.

Comment: <pre><code>selText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='sub_head'][text()='Language']/following-sibling::td//li[@class='sel']/a").text
print "selText={}".format(selText)</code></pre>         But prints "selText = "   At least beginning to see how to mash xpath items together!

Comment: One thing you can do is to test the XPath on your path. You can open up the Chrome dev toolbar and type in `$x("xpath goes here")` and see if it returns the element you want. It's a quick way to test your XPaths without having to update your Selenium script and run it to find out if it's working.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks.. I am getting closer just do not fully understand xpath, however I have this `elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='sub_head'][text()='Language']/following-sibling::td").text
print "elem={}".format(elem)  #  prints English`  Similarly changing "Language" to 'Country / Region' sill print the selected element there as well .  using your $x() trick I can see  `$x("//td[@class='sub_head'][text()='Language']/following-sibling::td//li[@class='sel']")` will show `<li id="langEN" class="sel">  <a href="javascript:">English</a>`

Comment: but putting a .text on that will not give me 'English'??  I am not sure why.  (again thanks for all the help!!)

Comment: Did you try the full XPath in the browser? Does it return the expected `A`?

Comment: yes!  so `$x("//td[@class='sub_head'][text()='Language']/following-sibling::td//li[@class='sel']//a")` will return `<a href="javascript:">English</a>` but doing `$x(<same>).text` returns undefined

Comment: Almost there I think!  inside Chrome, if I do `$x("//*[@id='lang']/../../../div/ul/li[@class='sel']/a/text()")`  I get a response of `[  "English"]`  However, if inside Python I try `selLang = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lang']/../../../div/ul/li[@class='sel']/a/text()")`  it crashes.  So, how do I translate the `$x()` to Python/Selenium equilivant?

Comment: oh should have included, in the above if I do `selLang = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lang']/../../../div/‌​ul/li[@class='sel']/‌​a").text` it returns nothing

Comment: That's really strange... I'm not sure why it's not working. Since you know that the XPath is working in the browser, grab the element using the same XPath in Selenium and dump the outerHTML and see what you get. I'm curious to see if it's finding the same element and contains the text.

Comment: I think I have it!   I think the reason is because it is a list, only showing one item, the actual items are not shown.  I tried `langSelectBtn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lang']/..")` then `langSelectBtn.click()` then `selectedLang= langSelectBtn.text` and finally `print "selectedLang = {}".format(selectedLang)` and I get English!    My apologies on not fully understanding how to use the 'comment' section to add proper code blocks and how ugly this looks.  Thank you very much on all the help!!!

Comment: Think I did it, clicked the answered and tried to 'upvote' it, really appreciate the help!